# Is "Spider-Man: Far From Home" set before or after "Avengers: Endgame"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

The trailer for *Spider-Man: Far From Home* has just been released:

With Tom Holland being in this film it gives some interesting insight into what might happen in *Avengers: Endgame*. However, that depends on when it is set in the in universe timeline.

Where does *Spider-Man: Far From Home* come in the MCU timeline? Is it before or after *Avengers: Endgame*?

Comment: the idea is that spider man, along with probably most other people, will be brought back. Until we see the actual film we can't know exactly what that will look like

Comment: A more ambitious Marvel would have set it right in the *middle* of Endgame.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So far the official answer is [After](https://www.express.co.uk/entertainment/films/1072558/Spiderman-Far-From-Home-when-setting-Avengers-Endgame-Peter-Parker-dead-Infinity-War). As of Summer 2017:

> According to Amy Pascal, the producer, Far From Home will start just immediately after the finale of Avengers: Endgame.
>
> She added: “And we are starting now the next one which will start a few minutes after Avengers 4 wraps as a story.”

The full quote can be found in [this Fandom article from June 2017](https://www.fandom.com/articles/exclusive-sonys-spider-man-movies-happen-in-the-same-reality-as-the-mcu):

> “What I think we should focus on is this Spider-Man who started in Civil War and then has this movie, and then will be in the Avengers movie. And we are starting now the next one which will start a few minutes after Avengers 4 wraps as a story,” Pascal reveals.

That's not to say, of course, that they have not changed their mind, or will not change their minds.

Of course, now, we know that it's set afterwards because the trailer for *Far from Home* has

> graffiti memorializing the deceased Tony Stark, who died during *Endgame*.

Comment: For the sake of completeness you could add that it was revealed in a [Fandom exclusive](https://www.fandom.com/articles/exclusive-sonys-spider-man-movies-happen-in-the-same-reality-as-the-mcu) (which the article apparently "forgot" to point to) one year and a half ago; foreshadowing being what it is in the MCU that could be tweaked but well...